# Yet another two column div query

Tags: html, css

What I would like is for a two column CSS layout, with a fixed sidebar (on the right), let's say 300px wide, and for a fluid left hand column that would expand to fit the screen size and height and THEN to provide a vertical scroll bar on the left hand column if the content requires it.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {margin:0px;}
#outer { 
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height:608px; 
  background: #ddd; 
} 

#inner1 { 
  float: right;/* Make this div as wide as its contents */ 
  width:300px;
  padding:10px;
  background: #fdd; 
} 

#inner2 { 
  overflow: hidden;/* Make this div take up the rest of the horizontal space, and no more */ 
  padding:10px;
  background: #ddf; 

#divScroll { 
  overflow: scroll; 
  height:600px; 
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="outer"> 
<div id="inner1"> 
    inner div 1. Some text... 
</div> 
<div id="inner2">
<div id="divScroll">

    inner div 2... <br />
    inner div 3... <br />
    inner div 2... <br />

.
.
    enough text here to make it scroll !
.
.
    inner div 2... <br />
    inner div 2... <br />
    inner div 2... <br />
    inner div 2... <br />
    </div>
</div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean from but I think you want something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/s8uLG/3/

You set your container up with overflow set to hidden, then on each div add negative margin-bottom and equal positive padding-bottom.

```
#container { overflow: hidden; }
#container div { float: left; background: #ccc; width: 200px; margin-bottom: -2000px; padding-bottom: 2000px; }
#container .col2 { background: #eee; }

<div id="container">
   <div>
        <p>Content 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
   </div>
</div>
```